# How to vertical-center Twitter Bootstrap 3 modal?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, vertical-alignment

I've been trying to vertical center the Boostrap 3 modal dialog without sucess. How can that be accomplished?

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve vertical alignment center on Bootstrap 3 modal like that :

```
.modal-vertical-centered {
transform: translate(0, 50%) !important;
-ms-transform: translate(0, 50%) !important; /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: translate(0, 50%) !important; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

and add this css class to the "modal-dialog" container

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-vertical-centered">
...
```

jsFiddle working example : http://jsfiddle.net/U4NRx/

Comment: This removes the slide down animation effect.

Comment: Awesome mate.. it does removes the slide down effect but it just fades in and fades out at the center. So those who needs it to get centered .. its the way to go.

Comment: NOTE: that example doesn't work at all, if the content of the modal is long... beware, it only works if the content is short/small.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <style>
     .modal-vertical-centered {
         display: flex;
         align-items: center;
     }
 </style>

<div class="modal fade modal-vertical-centered" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
```